# Python Concatenate N dictionaries with highest values for each key

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

I would like to create a new dictionary from dictionaries.

- all keys in all dictionaries must be present in resulting dictionary
- all keys must be present only once
- value for key is highest value from all values in dictionaries

ex.

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':3}
d2 = {'a':5, 'd':5}
d3 = {'c':2, 'f':1}

d = {'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':5, 'f':1}
```

Also, I would like keys (that are strings) to be sorted, like in my example. I try with `update`. However, it is overwriting existing value with the newest value, not the highest value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d1 = {'a':1, 'b':3}
>>> d2 = {'a':5, 'd':5}
>>> d3 = {'c':2, 'f':1}
>>> Counter(d1) | Counter(d2) | Counter(d3)
Counter({'a': 5, 'd': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'f': 1})
```

This uses the union of [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) through [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

If you need the result sorted:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted((Counter(d1) | Counter(d2) | Counter(d3)).items()))
OrderedDict([('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 5), ('f', 1)])
```

This can be generalized for N dictionaries by using `reduce`

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import or_
>>> reduce(or_, map(Counter, (d1, d2, d3)))
Counter({'a': 5, 'd': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'f': 1})
```

Comment: That's a pretty dense one-liner.

Comment: @Blender Now I changed to use `Counter` instead and deleted other answer